# Prevent Key Default in Silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, c#-4.0

I'm having the following problem, I have a textbox and I want to tebla Tab precione when a particular action occurs, but the focus must be maintained.
I've tried
e.Handled = true;
but still continues by setting the focus to the next element.
How can I avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: 7 questions and not even one marked as answered? How about showing those who have attempted to help you in the past some appreciation by marking those questions as answered. People will be more likely to answer your questions in the future that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
    void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
  if(e.Key == Key.Tab)
      e.Handled = true;
    }
```

This does work in Silverlight 4. If I press tab on the textbox, nothing happens.